# Blender freezes when attempting to import FBX files

Tags: import, file-format

recently I started encountering an error - when I try to import .fbx files, Blender starts to eat more and more memory which causes the computer to freeze. It worked a week ago and I'm not aware of any changes to the system - I updated graphics card drivers but that was after the issue started appearing.

The files have been exported in Maya.

[image: log]

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any ideas for fixing this? Should I file a bug report?

I'm using Blender 2.77a (the problem appeared in 2.77 but it worked there before) on Windows 10 on Lenovo U510. I disabled Windows updates so there wasn't this kind of change.

Comment: How large are the FBX files you're trying to import? And when you say Blender eats memory during import, I'm assuming you mean RAM. How much RAM, exactly?

Comment: What happens when you run Blender as an Administrator and then you try the import?

Comment: @Fweeb All FBX files - I even created a simple one with a few basic shapes - same thing. It eats as much as it can - I have 8 GB RAM on my work computer and it fills all the free space up (the stuff not taken up by the OS or other applications).

Comment: @Kirbinator I'll give it a shot on monday when I'll get back to work - it works fine in 2.76 on Linux Mint at home

Comment: @Kirbinator running it as admin changed nothing

Comment: Just as a test, you may also want to try exporting to FBX from Blender and then re-importing. See if the problem shows up there. Also, there are different versions of the FBX format. What version of the format are you using from Maya? You may want to try down-converting to an older version of FBX.

Comment: @Fweeb turns out that worked - I thought to try it today and it imported it flawlessly. I'll look into how to make Maya export older versions. It's still weird though - I import those files easily to Blender on my Linux machine. If nothing else works, I'll start using Linux at work as well - I'm going to make it a dualboot so I can just reboot for Maya LT.

Comment: I've just had the same problem with Blender 2.69 on Linux Mint 17. Disk thrashing so bad I couldn't even get a terminal to work long enough to get the blender pid, to kill it - after 20 mins I had to give up and do a forced reboot!! The fbx file was from here: https://www.cgtrader.com/items/177405/download-page
I *think* I've imported a FBX before, but I'm now scared to try again :-)