# PC freezes when trying to import .fbx exported from Maya

Tags: import, .fbx

My whole PC freezes when I try to import .fbx files which where exported on a different PC from Maya to a .fbx file.

I need to physically hold the power button to shut down my PC because it won't unfreeze again after trying to import it.

How can this happen? I am not in control of the PC with Maya on it.

I am using Blender V2.77.

One of the files where the issue is occurring can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2UlKqRHB4gHckJfMVRQdzdmNU0

Comment: For me it freezes Blender for couple of seconds and then Couldn't open file 'C:\\Blender_temp\\ventilation\\ventilation.fbx' shows up.

Comment: But why does that happen?

Comment: Check here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51152/blender-freezes-when-attempting-to-import-fbx-files

Comment: He installed another OS, I think that is a bit extreme for only one program that needs that.